# Rows Disappearing on check box click GoogleAppscripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I received help on this same code here before and it was working really great! I am very thankful for stackoverflow and all who contribute and help each other out. We have been using this sheet for awhile now and have noticed that rows were going missing. Right now, users can check a box to move the selected row to another tab within the sheet. Sometimes, not all the time, it will select a row and only move the row beneath it to the intended sheet and dropping the actual row selected. Where? I Have No Idea...SO! I started over with a new sheet and it's still happening. I think I narrowed it down to the line that refers to the ".getLastRow" command. I've tried .getActiveRow and that didn't work. Is there an alternative to getLastRow that is specific to ONLY the row selected by check box? I think it thinks the row beneath is the last row and pulls that over.

Also, if you know of a better way of doing this please let me know. Are there formulas or arrays that could do this better? I have a habit of overcomplicating things...so maybe code is not necessary?
Anyway, Thanks for your time!!

**Other Formulas used:** "=ARRAYFORMULA('Intake Responses'!B2:L)" and "=query('To ABDI'!A2:N, "SELECT * where J = 'No'")"

[Video of disappearance](https://youtu.be/RXVBLzXlMQE)

[Link to New Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rp54GrozIsB_XYr0378MuRu_Af-Jyi6lQI-VyN-ecrs/edit?usp=sharing)

Code:

```
function onForm(){
  
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sort");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("To ABDI");
  var r = s.getLastRow();
  var col = s.getLastColumn();
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,11);
    s.getRange(r, 1, 1,col).copyTo(target);
    targetSheet.getRange('O2:O').uncheck();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 0,15).activate().insertCheckboxes();
}

function onEdit() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Upcoming
  // target sheet of move to named Current
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "To ABDI" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule');
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,15);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    targetSheet.getRange('O2:O').uncheck();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 0,16).activate().insertCheckboxes();
  }
}

function onEditF() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Upcoming
  // target sheet of move to named Current
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Schedule" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Followup');
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,15);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    targetSheet.getRange('O2:O').uncheck();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 0,16).activate().insertCheckboxes();
  }
}

function onEditB() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Upcoming
  // target sheet of move to named Current
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Followup" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule');
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,15);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    targetSheet.getRange('O2:O').uncheck();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 0,16).activate().insertCheckboxes();
  }
}

function onEditD() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Upcoming
  // target sheet of move to named Current
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Schedule" && r.getColumn() == 16 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,16);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}

function onEditFD() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Upcoming
  // target sheet of move to named Current
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Followup" && r.getColumn() == 16 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,16);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the problems in the code is using `activeRange` and `activeSheet` when you can just use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

#### Modified Script

For me after changing that bit of code and making a copy of your sheet solved the issue:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Moved the checked row in `To ABDI` to `Schedule` 
  // And removing the moved row and uncheck
  var ss = e.source;
  let r = e.range;
  var s = e.range.getSheet();

  if(s.getName() == "To ABDI" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
    // Get edited range (row and number of columns)
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    
    // Retrieveing the target sheet and range
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule');
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,15);
    
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    
    // Delete moved sheet
    s.deleteRow(row);

    targetSheet.getRange('O2:O').uncheck();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 0,16).activate().insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

#### Result

[GIF of the modified solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g50h9.jpg)

#### Reference

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Current Selection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)

Comment: Wow. I'm floored by your efforts here. Thank you so much for going through all this; testing, rewriting, capturing a gif and posting references. Saying that I really appreciate you and your efforts doesn't quite cover it but I'll start there. Thank you so much for your time. I made this changes this morning and have told the staff to get in there and see if we can "break" it together. It's looking pretty good so far and we have been clicking all around :). SOOOO thankful!